How to create an API authorization with the latest IOS SST and AWS
I want to create an API with the new SST v3 aka ION SST.
Docs don't say much about auth-related things and I feel confused.
I have a separate Next.js app and now I want to create a backend infrastructure on AWS using the latest ION SST but I don't know how to use AWS Cognito to secure my API endpoints (preferably with JWT). My Next.js app will also use Cognito to authorize users on the front end.
Did anyone manage to create such a BE setup? Docs and examples don't say much.
